# add to css with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

How can I add the a css rule say for example

```
for (i to 10)
   .left= .left + 150
```

I tried something like this but I doesn't wrork

```
$(this).after("'style='left:'+1500+'px'");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, but it looks like you are looking for a animation. You can check demo **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/5aSLN/)**, but the `for` loop runs fast that you don't even see the effect.

JQuery has [.animate()](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/animate/&ei=rnboUYzYBKXG7AbepoGYAg&usg=AFQjCNEbtYj_CVrTF4Rx7m_-wysrfpbSQw&sig2=Pxzmoy2BsyJvpnCvKXpWpA&bvm=bv.49478099,d.ZGU), could be worth checking.

```
var le = 150;
for (var i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    le += 150;
    $(this).css('left', le);

}
```